# Terminology for differentiating models which are stationary versus which imitate functions of the original

Tags: terminology

If I have a model ship, car, aircraft, railroad, etc. what is the correct terminology to differentiate the following:

1. a stationary model, which is inert and does nothing, for example it has no moving parts even if the real life example would have. Is that the correct name, "stationary model"?
2. a functioning model, which is powered, and has motors etc. and for example can be remote controlled. Is it "functioning model" or "functional model", or is there a better word for it?

Answer (score 1):

"Stationary model" is pretty good for the first case, maybe a little too technical for general conversation, but in the right context absolutely correct. "Functional model" should be replaced by "mechanical model," or "remote controlled model," if it's actually that. The term "functional model," would spark for most native English speakers, a *working* model, as opposed to a *broken* model, or *non-functioning* model/device.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can **"function model"** be used, or is it grammatically incorrect? The technical meaning should be actually "a model with function/functions" so not the verb `it functions` but the word `funcion` as in mathematics. In more than one language I found the correct term, and it includes the word `function`. Not as "it is functional" but as in "it has functions".

Comment: The problem with mechanical is that a stationary model can also be mechanical, it just does not have any power to move on its own. Remote control is also too specific.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, *stationary* is not an appropriate term to use for non-functional models because most working model steam engines and many working model internal-combustion engines are [stationary engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_engine).

The term *working model* is widely used to refer to reduced-size but functional copies of larger items, and *model* by itself often is used to refer to reduced-size non-functional copies of items.
If you find *model* by itself inadequate to express non-functional status, you can preface it with non-working, non-functioning, or non-functional.  On numerous miniature-mechanical-model sites, *non-working* is the term commonly used; on some firearms sites, *non-functioning*; and on AI and neuroscience sites, *non-functional*.  Alternately, refer to *[cosmetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosmetic)* models.  As an adjective, *cosmetic* means "External or superficial; pertaining only to the surface or appearance of something".